# How to access Windows files from Centos 7 Virtual Box?

Tags: centos, mount, windows, virtualbox

I am wondering how I can access my Windows files through a Centos 7 Linux Machine located in virtual box?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure shared folders, it is in the virtual box configuration tool. I don't know if you have to do anything to enable this on the MS-Windows host. On a Linux host you have to add user to group `vboxusers` (this is only needed to enable shared folders, and nothing else).

You may need to restart the virtual machine, to get the share to work.

Comment: no configuration necessary on the windows end.

Comment: @TylerChambers thought so, MS-Windows is low on security, though I do wonder what this is securing.